# Grails/ HTML: display images and video in same carousel

Tags: html, css, image, grails, video

I am uploading content to my web app via AWS S3 and I am having trouble displaying both images and videos in the same carousel.

This code below is my carousel navigator and below that is the actual full sized image being displayed.

```
<div class="content">

            <div class="slider-nav">
                <g:each in="${event.contents}" var="content">
                    <img height = "50px" class = "event-content" src = "${content.url}" />
                </g:each>
            </div>

            <div class="content-holder">
                <div class="slider-for">

                    <g:each in="${event.contents}" var="content">
                        <img class = "event-content" src = "${content.url}" />
                    </g:each>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div
```

As you can see it is iterating through my content table and setting the image src to the url's found in there. I want to have both images and videos in the same carousel but I cannot figure out how to do so.

Any help or alternative ideas is appreciated.

Comment: So what you have above works but you want to add videos into the mix? Where are the videos coming from?

Comment: Yes exactly, videos are coming from the same bucket on AWS. A bucket subdirectory is created for each event and each of those will have all content in there for each event

Comment: So basically I'm hoping some sort of if statement to check if its an <img> or a <video>

Comment: So you have to base this off the url? Can you provide an example of each

Comment: Yes I'd need to base it off the url. Here is a screenshot of my db with a video and image https://i.gyazo.com/c19faaefb783e4877d15390c564c14b0.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like the following. If you're going to show additional video formats to mp4 you'd have to alter the g:if test.

```
    <g:each in="${event.contents}" var="content">
        <g:if test="${content.url.endsWith('.mp4')}">
            <video controls>
                <source src="${content.url}" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </g:if>
        <g:else>
            <img src="${content.url}" />
        </g:else>
        <br>
    </g:each>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you